Can't figure out how to open a file using PyCharm
I'm new to coding and doing a coursera course, and we just got into opening and reading files. I have this file 'words.txt' and I'm trying to open and read it but keep getting:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'.
Even though the words.txt is in my pythonProject file and the working directory is:
Current working directory: /Users/me/PycharmProjects/pythonProject

I had to resort to the absolute path, but I don't want to do that everytime I open a file.
Do you have to use the absolute path every time even though the working directory is matched?

If you put print(os.getcwd()) in front of the line where you try to load the text file, does it return the expected location?

You basically have 2 choices:  full absolute path, or the path from the location from which your program is run.  The latter is usually the top level of your project, but it can be changed.  In PyCharm's run menu, it is the Working Directory

@Anonymous  I'm pretty sure. :print(os.getcwd())
/Users/me/PycharmProjects/pythonProject

@AirSquid Gotcha. But for the later I think I changed it and it still doesn't run correctly unless im changing the wrong thing. Is this what I need to change? SS : https://imgur.com/a/gvFKtQc

You are looking at the template.  Don't change that.  Go up where it says "current file" and at the bottom there is an edit configuration.  But standby for a sec...  lemme write you an answer.

If you right click on your program and select "run" it will make a run configuration for your program.  Then if you go up to the run config at the top and edit it, you'll get a screen as shown below, which shows the "working directory"
By default, it is the location of the program.  If this is the case, the reference to words.txt should be just the filename, words.txt (current directory) and it should work fine.
If you ran it from pythonProject (top level of your project), you'd need to change the file reference in your program to Module_2/words.txt
is is usually "standard" to run things from top level of project, but it depends on a lot of things you'll learn later...
You should also get in the habit of not using spaces in directory or file names because you will need to "escape" them to make them reference-able in text.  (trust me).  Just rename them.


Thanks for the help! I tried this over and over, but for some reason it didn't fully accept this so i had to use  os.chdir() to manually change my directory which finally worked.
